# Count lines which have even numbers in turn with javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a script that grabs lines from textarea and sees for each of them if it's even or uneven.

It should go like this. It takes lines from textarea:

- 11
- 12
- 8
- 55
- 555
- 1

And counts how many even or uneven goes in turn:

- 1
- 2 (here's the final line of counting these two even lines)
- br (I want 
   on every line that is counting and it is not final)
- 3
- br
- br

I have wrote this code already, but it only can say if it's even or uneven. I need it to count evens or unevens in turn, but I can't figure it out how to do this. Does anyone have some ideas?

https://jsfiddle.net/xk861vf9/5/

```
function isEven(n) {
   return n % 2 == 0;
}
function isOdd(n) {
   return Math.abs(n % 2) == 1;
}
```

Comment: what do you mean count them ?

Comment: how 554 should be treated ? what `br` mean ?

Comment: Why `isOdd` uses `Math.abs` ?

Comment: iterate through your lines and call isEven() and isOdd() for each. Keep a variable that gets increased with each even or odd number and print this in each iteration

Comment: Simon, if you want to get 2 results which are : count of even numbers and count of odd numbers, it would be enough to deal with a single function

Comment: I thought it will be in hand to had two functions if empty space would come up to fill it with <br>.. What about counting them I have an example on jsfiddle too. Check the link https://jsfiddle.net/xk861vf9/1/

Comment: is [this](https://jsfiddle.net/xk861vf9/2/) what you are looking for?

Comment: @RejithRKrishnan No. Check the example below on my fiddle link. It should append results like there.

Answer (score 2):

i assume that n is for the number you read in the line,

```
var evenCount=0, oddCount=0;
var digits = n.toString().split('');
for(var i =0; i <digits.length; i++){
    if(digits[i] % 2 ==0){
       evenCount +=1;
     }
    else
       oddCount +=1;
}
```

br will be printed if the value of the evenCount is not changed. you can use flag to check whether it has been changed.

Comment: Thanks, but I can't find a way to get this code to work as I need :( Maybe I am implementing it wrong? Check example on fiddle too, I have wrote html how it should look. https://jsfiddle.net/xk861vf9/4/

Answer (score 1):

Just don't use IDs as these should be unique per element, instead give them a common class name. use this way:

```js
function isEven(n) {
   return n % 2 == 0;
 }

 function isOdd(n) {
   return Math.abs(n % 2) == 1;
 }

 $(document).ready(function() {
   $(".sub").bind("click", function() { // <---common class for button
     $(this).prev(".res").html(""); // <-----common class for res div
     var even=0, odd=0; // <-----------initialise the counters for event and odd
     var arr = $(this).prevAll('textarea').first().val().split("\n"); // get the textarea value
     for (var i in arr) {
       if (isEven(arr[i])) {
         even++; // <----------count the evens
         $(this).prev(".res").append(arr[i] + " (even) <br>");
       } else if (isOdd(arr[i])) {
         odd++; // <-----------count the odds
         $(this).prev(".res").append(arr[i] + " (uneven) <br>");
       }
     }
     console.log('There are '+even+' even values and '+odd+' odd values.');
   });
 });
```

```css
textarea, .res{
  width: 100px;
  min-height: 300px;
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 24px;
}
.res{
  float: left;
  padding-top: 3px;
}
.sub{
  clear: both;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="text">
11
15
12
15
19
13
11
10
2
1</textarea>

<div class="res">
</div>

<button class="sub">
SUB
</button>

<br/>
---------------------------------------------
<br/>
Example:
<br/>
<textarea>
11
15
12
15
19
13
11
10
2
1
</textarea>

<div class="res">
</div>

<button class="sub">
SUB
</button>
```

Comment: Thanks, but it does not what it should. Please check "Example" on fiddle how it should look https://jsfiddle.net/xk861vf9/5/

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this?

```
function OveralCount(even,odd){ //object
    this.even = even;
    this.odd = odd;
}
function isEven(n) { //test for even numbers
   return n % 2 == 0;
}
function count(array){
    var even = 0;
    var odd = 0;
    for (var i=0;i<array.length;i++){
        if (isEven(array[i])){
            even++;
        }
    }
    return new OveralCount(even,(array.length-even));
}
```

Usage:

```
var count = count(YourArray);
var odd = count.odd;
var even = count.even;
```